# Get return type of a callback function which takes union as argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A function `foo` takes a callback that accepts either `string` or `number` and calls that callback with `"one"` and `1` arguments, which should give the return type of `result` as
`{ str: string[], num: number[] }`.

But in fact, the `result` variable has a type: `{ str: (string | number)[], num: (string | number)[] }` which does not correspond to the actual data returned.

```js
function foo<R>(cb: <S extends string | number>(s: S) => R) {
  return {
    str: cb("one"),
    num: cb(1),
  };
};

// I expect: { str: string[], num: number[] }
// I get: { str: (string | number)[], num: (string | number)[] }
const result = foo((s) => [s]);
```

How I can get the correct return type of a `foo` function?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=32#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AlAfACggIwC5E0BlRAUwA8oKwATAZ0UagCcYwBzRAH0TAgAtvgptcjYqQCUiALxZEGWQG8AsAChEiNhSgg2SdVu0t2xAjgBECClekAaTaYHCL+HAEZHzxAF8Abk1AzU0AejDEAElKKgAHCmhiFTM2YlYObgBtAF0HVyFiQRExXP9wyJiuPWTU4hwMzh5+YtE2aVz84vrG7j4Cto6c8o0IBFYdCkYQABsoeWRUHAbZBUQsxhzpAKA)

Comment: Your playground is broken.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible in TypeScript. There are solutions but they wouldn't work for more complicated examples and would probably exhibit undesirable behavior unexpectedly.

Comment: I agree with @kelly.  Without higher kinded types as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) there's no way to talk about this sort of operation in the abstract, and without a solution for inferring conditional generic types as in [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) or overload implementation analysis as in [ms/TS#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669) there's no way the compiler can see `s => [s]` as doing what you want.  You'd need [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLy34W) right now, and that's yucky.

Comment: I could write the above up as an answer if it fully addresses your question.  If not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please @jcalz mention me or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz yeah, you can write this as an answer, thanks